# Can I use the access token from facebook-ios-sdk to like page with uiwebview iframe with re-login?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I want to let the user the option to like facebook page with this code generator :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages

the problem is the using this code in iframe and uiwebview, facebook is asking the user to log again.

Is there way to use the access token from the facebook-ios-sdk login to prevent the user to login twice ?

Comment: I have same problem, it seems that there is no way for that.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to to tell the facebook sdk login method to log with webview from the app and not to login through the official facebook app.

this way, when the user like the page later, the access token already exist.

it's not perfect solution but works ok for one user.